# How to recursively group array objects with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am developing with Ionic 3 and I have a JSON data with the following format (see url):

https://jsonblob.com/5aed9990-0eb9-11e9-b29a-2d13328e5286

The task is to show Day wise time entries. Time entries are based on `punchType` - i:e `punchType == 0` means user is offline, `punchType == 1` means user is taking a break, `punchType == 2` means user is online.

Now how to efficiently write a function that returns a result array like the following (pseudo code):

```
    let arr = [
{"day": 1 January 2019, "totalOffline": ..., "totalBreak": ..., "totalOnline": ...},
{"day": 2 January 2019, "totalOffline": ..., "totalBreak": ..., "totalOnline": ...},
.. so on 
]
```

So that for each day - I can show total time entries grouped  with the corresponding label.

Please help.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: You can create a map containing an array of items based on the key for the property you wish to group on. What have you tried till now?

Comment: @Icepickle could not complete the recursive mapping .. help with code sample will be awesome

Comment: For me, what seems to be missing, would be a real sample output, and if you would like to calculate everything in your output already? Do you require the time calculation based on all punchTypes? Is it then still grouped per team? Is your data already sorted, or does it has to be sorted per time stamp still? I mean, what you are asking here is not a simple task, I guess its fair you show at least where you have failed, so we have an idea of the problems you were facing

Comment: @Icepickle I understand that this is not a simple task. When I map the array by date .. the resultant array does not have any other information - when I filter with punchType the days are taken together .. Yes I need time calculation based on punch type for each day .. so that I can show a list of days .. and under each day - I can show total time consumed for each 3 types of punch.

Comment: Would you have enough info, if I would show you how to do recursive grouping?

Comment: So if you want to do recursive grouping, you can try the [following code](https://jsfiddle.net/rjzegLh8/). I don't really care that much about the counting so maybe the other answers are good for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [
  {
    "endAt": 1546327200621,
    "endTime": 770,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.563032,
      "longitude": 88.3148152
    },
    "minutes": 1,
    "punchType": 2,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546327117421,
    "startTime": 768,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546327200621,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546327400397,
    "endTime": 773,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.563032,
      "longitude": 88.3148152
    },
    "minutes": 3,
    "punchType": 1,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546327200632,
    "startTime": 770,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546327400397,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546327696256,
    "endTime": 778,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.563032,
      "longitude": 88.3148152
    },
    "minutes": 1,
    "punchType": 2,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546327632210,
    "startTime": 777,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546327696256,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546327767380,
    "endTime": 779,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.563032,
      "longitude": 88.3148152
    },
    "minutes": 1,
    "punchType": 1,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546327696266,
    "startTime": 778,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546327767380,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546327895211,
    "endTime": 781,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.563032,
      "longitude": 88.3148152
    },
    "minutes": 2,
    "punchType": 2,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546327767387,
    "startTime": 779,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546327895211,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546333470799,
    "endTime": 874,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.5630407,
      "longitude": 88.3148147
    },
    "minutes": 92,
    "punchType": 1,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546327895220,
    "startTime": 781,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546333470799,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546333790500,
    "endTime": 879,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.5630407,
      "longitude": 88.3148147
    },
    "minutes": 5,
    "punchType": 2,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546333470807,
    "startTime": 874,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546333790500,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546333862414,
    "endTime": 881,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.5630407,
      "longitude": 88.3148147
    },
    "minutes": 1,
    "punchType": 1,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546333790510,
    "startTime": 879,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546333862414,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546333954030,
    "endTime": 882,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.5630407,
      "longitude": 88.3148147
    },
    "minutes": 1,
    "punchType": 2,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546333862422,
    "startTime": 881,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546333954030,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546334540130,
    "endTime": 892,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.5630316,
      "longitude": 88.3148142
    },
    "minutes": 8,
    "punchType": 1,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546334046035,
    "startTime": 884,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546334540130,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546335238707,
    "endTime": 903,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.5630331,
      "longitude": 88.3148138
    },
    "minutes": 11,
    "punchType": 2,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546334540140,
    "startTime": 892,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546335238707,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546339116332,
    "endTime": 968,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.5630331,
      "longitude": 88.3148138
    },
    "minutes": 64,
    "punchType": 1,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546335238717,
    "startTime": 903,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546339116332,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546349619259,
    "endTime": 1143,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.5630433,
      "longitude": 88.3147712
    },
    "minutes": 39,
    "punchType": 2,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546347236410,
    "startTime": 1103,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546349619259,
    "day": "1 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546412890343,
    "endTime": 758,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.5630341,
      "longitude": 88.3148131
    },
    "minutes": 2,
    "punchType": 2,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546412694492,
    "startTime": 754,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546412890343,
    "day": "2 January 2019"
  },
  {
    "endAt": 1546442735609,
    "endTime": 1255,
    "location": {
      "latitude": 22.5630316,
      "longitude": 88.3148142
    },
    "minutes": 6,
    "punchType": 1,
    "reverseGeocode": "..geocode here",
    "startAt": 1546442344340,
    "startTime": 1249,
    "teamRef": "-LQJBi69vfFfvU9Dmz-x",
    "timeStamp": 1546442735609,
    "day": "2 January 2019"
  }
]

var respTemplate = { totalOnline: 0, totalBreak: 0, totalOffline: 0 },
  response = []

data.forEach(item => {
  let findDay = response.filter(t => item.day == t.day),
    day
  if(findDay.length) day = findDay[0]
  else {
    day = { ...respTemplate, day: item.day }
    response.push(day)
  }
  
  let prop
  
  switch(item.punchType){
    case 0:
      prop = 'totalOffline'
      break;
    case 1:
      prop = 'totalBreak'
      break;
    case 2:
      prop = 'totalOnline'
      break;
  
  }
  
  day[prop] += item.minutes
  
})

console.log(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you could use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group your data by day, i added comments in the code to try to explain it.

```js
const parseData = url => $.get(url).then(data =>

  data.reduce((all, curr) => {

    // see if there's an object in the accumulator having the same day.
    const ndx = all.findIndex(e => e.day === curr.day)

    // if it exists, keep it in obj , create a new one otherwise.
    let obj = ndx > -1 ? all[ndx] : {
      day: curr.day,
      totalOffline: 0,
      totalBreak: 0,
      totalOnline: 0
    };

    // increment the properties according to the punch type
    curr.punchType === 0 ?
      obj.totalOffline += curr.minutes :
      curr.punchType === 1 ?
      obj.totalBreak += curr.minutes :
      obj.totalOnline += curr.minutes;

    // if it's a new object you'll need to push it to the list.
    ndx === -1 && all.push(obj)

    return all;
  }, [])
)

parseData('https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/5aed9990-0eb9-11e9-b29a-2d13328e5286')
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```